# AWS AppSync Event Subscription based on Location

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-elasticsearch

I understand how to perform geo-spatial queries through `AppSync` to find events within a distance range from a gps coordinate by attaching a resolver linked to `ElasticSesarch`, as [described here](https://youtu.be/mQBtbHKSdAQ?t=2015).

However, what if I want my client to subscribe to new events being created within this distance range as well?

1. user subscribes to a location
2. if an event is created near that location, notify user

I know I can attach resolver to subscription types but it seems like it forces you to provide a data source when I just want to filter subscriptions by checking distance between gps coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question and I would think there are a couple ways to solve this. The tough part here is that you are going to have figure out a way to ask the question "What subscriptions are interested in an event at this location". Here is one possible path forward.

The following assumes these schema parts:

```
// Whatever custom object has a location 
type Post {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  location: Location
}
input PublishPostInput {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  location: Location
  subscriptionID: ID
}
type PublishPostOutput {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  location: Location
  subscriptionID: ID
}

type Location {
  lat: Float,
  lon: Float
}
input LocationInput {
  lat: Float,
  lon: Float
}

# A custom type to hold custom tracked subscription information
# for location discover
type OpenSubscription {
  subscriptionID: ID!
  location: Location
  timestamp: String!
}
type OpenSubscriptionConnection {
  items: [OpenSubscription]
  nextToken: String
}

type Query {
  # Query elasticsearch index for relevant subscriptions
  openSubscriptionsNear(location: LocationInput, distance: String): OpenSubscriptionConnection
}
type Mutation {
  # This mutation uses a local resolver (e.g. a resolver with a None data source) and simply returns the input as is.
  publishPostToSubscription(input: PublishPostInput): PublishPostOutput
}
type Subscription {
  # Anytime someone passes an object with the same subscriptionID to the "publishPostToSubscription" mutation field, get updated.
  listenToSubscription(subscriptionID: ID!): PublishPostOutput
    @aws_subscribe(mutations:["publishPostToSubscription"])
}
```

Assuming you are using DynamoDB as your primary source of truth, setup a DynamoDB stream that invokes a "PublishIfInRange" lambda function. That "PublishIfInRange" function would look something like this

```
// event - { location: { lat, lon }, id, title, ... }
function lambdaHandler(event) {

  const relevantSubscriptions = await callGraphql(`
    query GetSubscriptions($location: LocationInput) {
      openSubscriptionsNear(location:$location, distance: "10 miles") {
        subscriptionID
      }
    }
  `, { variables: { location: event.location }})

  for (const subscription of relevantSubscriptions) {
    callGraphql(`
      mutation PublishToSubscription($subID: ID!, $obj: PublishPostInput) {
        publishPostToSubscription(input: $obj) {
          id
          title
          location { lat lon }
          subscriptionID
        }
      }
    `, { variables: { input: { ...subscription, ...event }}})
  }
}
```

You will need to maintain a registry of subscriptions indexed by location. One way to do this is to have your client app call a mutation that creates a subscription object with a location and subscriptionID (e.g. `mutation { makeSubscription(loc: $loc) { ... } }` assuming you are using $util.autoId() to generate the subscriptionID in the resolver). After you have the subscriptionID, you can make the subscription call through graphql and pass in the subscriptionID as an argument (e.g.`subscription { listenToSubscription(subscriptionID: "my-id") { id title location { lat lon } } }`). When you make this above subscription call, AppSync creates a topic and authorizes the current user to subscribe to that topic. The topic is unique to subscription field being called and the set of arguments passed to the subscription field. In other words, the topic only receives objects

Now whenever an object is created, the record goes to the lambda function via DynamoDB streams. The lambda function queries elasticsearch for all open subscriptions near that object and then publishes a record to each of those open subscriptions.

I believe this should get you reasonably far but if you have millions of users in tight quarters you will likely run into scaling issues. Hope this helps

Comment: To scale this you can get smarter about how you split up subscriptionID. For example you could have your map split up into N small chunks and then on you client have them subscribe to the Y closest chunks in the grid and do any fine grain filtering on the client. This way you would only ever have at most N subscriptionIDs so the fan out proceedure would be much smaller than if each user had their own subscription.

Comment: considering the scaling issue and the cost on user end for maintaining many subscription channels, would it be more reasonable to just query more frequently to make sure user is updated at near real-time?

Comment: Polling is a much simpler and cost effective option if true real-time isn't a requirement